# Rails - defining cancan ability using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

When defining abilities in the cancan Ability class...

Is this:

```
 can :manage, Area, :location => { :company => { :manager => { :user_id => user.id } } }
```

The same as this:

```
 can :manage, Area do |area|
      area.location.company.manager.user_id == user.id
 end
```

I'm just trying to better understand defining an ability without using a block.  Is one way better (maybe faster) than the other?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without a block? The speed difference, if any, will be negligible and the first way you posted is just ugly/hard to read/understand.

Comment: I agree the first example is ugly...and harder to read.  I do appreciate the one liner.  However, I see both in the real world and just wanted to make sure I was understanding the correct usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two should be the same, however the second way is much clearer if anyone else is reading your code. I would definitely recommend using the second way. If what bothers you is taking up multiple lines, you could just write:

```
can( :manage, Area ) {|area| area.location.company.manager.user_id == user.id }
```

That's possibly cleaner (when stacked with a bunch of other rules) than either other option.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  And, I definitely appreciate the one liner...  Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a syntax error in this one liner example?  Im getting undefined method 'Area'.  However, rewriting the block so it is not a one liner...works fine.

Comment: These two are not equivalent. 

The block version wont allow you to use accessible_by to perform a query. 

Its best to not use blocks when possible for this reason. Otherwise you need to define the query separately.

Answer (score 2):

As it says here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#fetching-records

the big advantage of using a block is that it accessible_by will still work. If you use a block and also want to use accessible_by you need to add in the SQL where clause manually, which is not quite DRY and to be avoided if possible IMO.